# vtable error. "vtable for ETRun", referenced from:

Tags: c++-cli

I have an object called Run. I can instantiate in header of a class. But, when i try to do the same .cpp file the above error was popped out.

> vtable error.  "vtable for Run",
>   referenced from: 
>         __ZTV5Run$non_lazy_ptr in Para.o

```
string Para::name()
{ 
 Run* newRun = new Run;

 return mName;
}
```

how can i get out of this error...

Answer (score 0):

This probably happens because `Run` is a derived class, and it has a declaration of some virtual function but this function is not implemented.

Try to check whether your problem is [this case](http://www.icce.rug.nl/documents/cplusplus/cplusplus14.html#l239).